# Magento help: Install Magento 2 through composer

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I try to install Magento 2.4.5 through composer but showing an error "Could not find package project-community-edition with version 2.4.5."

I used cmd:composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ project-community-edition:2.4.5 in the folder C:\xampp\htdocs in cmd.

following is my composer.jason file.

```
{
    "name": "mycompany/sample-module-minimal",
    "description": "A module that creates a page in the Magento admin area",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.4.5",
    "license": [
      "OSL-3.0",
      "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
      "php": "~8.2.0"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
           "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
       }
   ],
    "autoload": {
      "files": [ "registration.php" ],
      "psr-4": {
        "MyCompany\\ExampleAdminNewPage\\": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's hard to tell here if you're asking a programming question or just trying to install Magento. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I just try to install Magento.

Comment: @KumarAnand - Then I'd suggest you post on https://serverfault.com

Comment: bro unable to understand your query,but i found something is missing in your command please try this one,```composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ 
magento/project-community-edition:2.4.5```.if still problem remains please share the error screenshot

Answer (score 0):

change your php version, 2.4.5 compatible with php 8.1
see [magento 2.4.5 requirement](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've got that composer file?

That's an example you'd use when creating a Magento module.

Remove the composer file altogether, the composer create-project command should create a package for you, including a composer.json file.

Comment: In my case it says, composer.jason file missing in the root folder. So I create a composer file. But after reinstalling except the C drive then I don't need to create composer.jason file.